# How to display SSRS report in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following ASP.net code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<rsweb:ReportViewer runat="server" ID="MyReportViewer" Width="100%" Height="100%" ZoomMode="FullPage" ClientIDMode="Static" SizeToReportContent="True" KeepSessionAlive="true">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

C# code:

```
string strWG = "WG Testing";
MyReportViewer.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://myserv1/ReportServer/"); // Report Server URL
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/IR/OB"; // Report Name
ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[2];
param[0] = new ReportParameter("User", "Executive");
param[1] = new ReportParameter("WorkGroups", strWG);
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(param); //throws an error: "Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'myserv1' failed...
MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
MyReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
MyReportViewer.ShowPromptAreaButton = true;
MyReportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;

MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

When I look at the Event Viewer in the server where the ASP.net application is installed, I see the following:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpParseException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.AddAssemblyDependency(String assemblyName, Boolean addDependentAssemblies)
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistrationCore(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry nsRegisterEntry)
   at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
```

How can I resolve the issue.

Comment: o you actually have two errors happening at the same time? I mean you say that MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(param); //throws an error: "Unable to automatically [...]"
But that also you get another error in the Event Viewer. Which one is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the "//throws an error:..." is when I am debugging but the event viewer is when I am running the deployed application in a browser.

Comment: Oh ok. Try user's solution. That may work as it is my guess too.

Comment: Didn't solve the issue but the report itself is having issue so maybe it's not my application but the report itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll** locate in your visual studio reportviewer folder into bin folder (website).

Comment: Didn't solve the issue but the report itself is having issue so maybe it's not my application but the report itself.

Comment: Check if it is present in the GAC too ? By the way check common dll too : **Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll**

Comment: Thank you. I will check it also.

Comment: So @SiKni8 do this help ?

Comment: It didn't help. I had to install it in the GAC in the server unfortunately. I will accept it as it was a start :) Thank you.